# Issue with Model Derivative translation

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

We have been using Model derivative translation to convert our textured mesh obj files to svf format to display in the forge viewer for many months now. For the past 3 days, the translation results in a weird mesh in the viewer. If we use meshlab to open our obj files, they look perfectly fine.

**Have there been any updates? Is there something we can check?**

Used meshlab to view the obj file to make sure our texture model is OK.

[image: Attaching snapshot of the model (obj) viewed using meshlab]

[image: Attaching snapshot of the converted model viewed using forge viewer]

[Attaching snapshot of the OBJ model viewed in viewer.autodesk.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aEP9.png)

Update May 29th:

Looks like the issue is fixed. This problem was similar to [Translation of zip file (contains object and material file with different colors) results to a viewables of single color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322902/translation-of-zip-file-contains-object-and-material-file-with-different-colors).

Comment: Hi,
Have you tried loading your model in viewer.autodesk.com ? and check if the result is same.

Comment: Hi, Yes I just updated my post with the link to a snapshot from viewer.autodesk.com. I uploaded the same obj (plus images) as used to view in meshlab, but the result is still all wrong. Meshlab displays the same model just fine.

Comment: My issue was similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322902/translation-of-zip-file-contains-object-and-material-file-with-different-colors, where the translation was resulting in only the first material being applied. It seems to be fixed now.