# Translation of zip file (contains object and material file with different colors) results to a viewables of single color

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Till a few days back the translation was working as expected. I was able to see the viewables with the color scheme mentioned in obj and mat file. But now same translation is giving wrong results(viewables). It applies only one color to all the objects and nodes !!!

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Have you tried loading your model in viewer.autodesk.com ? and check if the result is same.

Comment: The resulting image on the right side was open in forge viewer itself. And the one (expected) on the left side, it was opened in meshlab.

Comment: ok, please mention viewer version.
you may be viewing in your dev env, once try uploading your file here and check if the result is same: https://viewer.autodesk.com/designviews

Comment: I can see the same issue on the link you have provided.

Comment: I am using this script for my viewer "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js" which takes the latest one I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed, thanks for reporting.